# Add two duplication to a generated list of all combinations of numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have funded a function to  create a list of all possible combination of my values. I just want to be able to duplicate the first and second values to the third and fourth positions.

```
function cartesian() {
    var r = [], arg = arguments, max = arg.length-1;
    function helper(arr, i) {
        for (var j=0, l=arg[i].length; j<l; j++) {
            var a = arr.slice(0); // clone arr
            a.push(arg[i][j]);
            if (i==max)
                r.push(a);
            else
                helper(a, i+1);
        }
    }
    helper([], 0);
    return r;
}

var c = cartesian([0.1,0.2], [0.1,0.2],[0.8],[0.8],[0.7]);
```

C is ::: [0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.7], [0.1,0.2,0.8,0.8,0.7], [0.2,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.7], [0.2,0.2,0.8,0.8,0.7]

I want to convert C to::: 
[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.7], [0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,0.8,0.8,0.7], [0.2,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.8,0.8,0.7], [0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.8,0.8,0.7]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're saying is equivalent to pushing first/second 2 positions back and copy and push to beginning of array. So you can just use `slice(begin, end)` Or you can add them to beginning of array as shown here.

```js
const data = [0.1,0.2,0.8,0.8,0.7];

const mapped = [...data.slice(0,2),...data]; // OR [data[0], data[1], ...data];

console.log(mapped);

// Usage
const c = cartesian([0.1,0.2], [0.1,0.2],[0.8],[0.8],[0.7]).map((arr)=> [arr[0], arr[1], ...arr]);

// Or this
const c = cartesian([0.1,0.2], [0.1,0.2],[0.8],[0.8],[0.7]).map((arr)=> [...arr.slice(0,2), ...arr]);
```

Comment: How can I add the _slice_ to the cartesian function? This function must create hundreds of different combinations, here, I just provided a sample list. Thanks again.

Comment: Updated the answer. You can just use `map()` as shown. If you know for definite you only have to clone 2 values I would use the first option. It avoids slicing/decontructing the sliced array.